# Check div visibility

Tags: jquery

There is some number of div's which will be in one wrapper, like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

There can be any amount of divs `container`. How could I trigger event only if ***all*** of this divs aren't visible?
I was thinking about something like that, but code seems not to be working:

```
if (!$('.container:visible')) {alert("no container found")}
```

or

```
if ($('.container:visible') == 0) {alert("no container found")}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k4eKf/

What's the possible ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
$('.container').is(":visible");
```

If this returns true, then it means that some div with class `.container` is visible. You will need the condition:

```
if(!$('.container').is(":visible")){
  //all container are hidden
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vck3g/)**

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. I will accept your answer after timer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `is()` function to check the existence of property.

Use:

```
var visible=$('.container').is(":visible");

if(visible==true)
{
//Do something here
}
```

Read the docs about `is()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/is/)